# Correct word with errors (cyclic codes)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following generator matrix:

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0\end{pmatrix}$$

After Gauss method and $H = [-P^T\hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm}I\hspace{1mm}]$ I get the parity matrix:

$$H = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to correct the word $(1 0 0 1 1 0)$. First I calculate the syndrome which gives me:
$$s = H\cdot r' = (1100)$$

After that I don't know wheter it's possible to get the corrected word since the parity capability correction is $1$. In case it is, how should I proceed to get the corrected word and what steps should I follow?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The code is simple (small size) and linear. You are trying to correct a one-error transmission.

To correct from the syndrome (Hy): by considering all the possible error positions (there are 6 of them), you can establish a correspondence (a table) between error positions and the syndrome. This is performed assuming the original data is the all-zero vector.

If your syndrome corresponds to one of these calculated one-error syndromes, then you can correct one error.